# IE11 Font Face Issue

Tags: css, apache, windows-8.1, font-face, internet-explorer-11

Having a bit of a mysterious issue with IE11/Windows 8.1 and it seems to only affect *some* users. I have a font that's generated from fontello.com that works in every browser I can think of, it's sweet and bullet proof. All was fine til this past week when I logged into our software and the font-face wasn't loading properly. I've spent a good chunk of my day searching, googling, and yearning for an answer but I'm finding no such luck.

Here's what I've found:

The font works in a staging environment that's....similar to the live environment. Staging is Apache 2.2.25 and live is Apache 2.2.3. In staging, when on IE11 the font pulls through just fine, and the Content-Type header comes out as `application/vnd.ms-fontobject` and the font loads fine. On live the fonts are either blank/empty or they come through as Chinese/Japanese characters and the Content-Type comes through as text/plain. On another computer I've tried this out in Windows 8.1/IE11 and it worked just fine and the type was still text/plain, but on my home computer it still has issues with text/plain. I haven't had these issues on IE11 with Windows 7 or 8 I've tested on other computers, but maybe I don't have enough computers to fully test this out. Here are some screenshots for clarification.

What it should look like

[image: What it should look like]

What it looks like in IE11/Windows 8.1

[image: What it looks like in IE11/Windows 8.1]

Here is the CSS I'm using that's generated from Fontello. One other interesting note is IE11 is trying to pull the /fonts/sweeticons.eot?303474737448#iefix, not the /fonts/sweeticons.eot?303474737448. In staging, it will only download /fonts/sweeticons.eot?303474737448 but on live it tries to download /fonts/sweeticons.eot?303474737448#iefix and /fonts/sweeticons.woff?303474737448 and /fonts/sweeticons.ttf?303474737448, but none of them are working correctly or maybe that's why they aren't working correctly. When viewing developer tools, IE11 recognizes all the classes for the font that should be loading, but all the statements are crossed out (as if the class is being overridden by a class lower in the file, or by an inline style):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'sweeticons';
  src: url('/fonts/sweeticons.eot?303574737448');
  src: url('/fonts/sweeticons.eot?303474737448#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/fonts/sweeticons.woff?302374734478') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/sweeticons.ttf?303374737448') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/sweeticons.svg?303274734478#sweeticons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="fa-"]:before, [class*=" fa-"]:before {
  font-family: "sweeticons";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: .2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-left: .2em;
}

[class^="fa-"]:hover,[class*=" fa-"]:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

And here's a quick screenshot of the live server and what it tries to do:

[image: Live server requests]

And here some header info for the live eot file:

```
Date: Wed, 24 Sep 2014 17:49:06 GMT  
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)  
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 20:32:15 GMT  
Accept-Ranges: bytes  
Vary: Accept-Encoding  
Content-Encoding: gzip  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8  
Content-Length: 24212  
Connection: close
```

And also, just to be crystal clear in case you don't notice from the CSS above, this has nothing to do with CORS, or cross domain anything, these are local files hosted directly on the server. I have snooped around on google and the best that I can come up with is to wait and see if another update from Microsoft will fix these issues as it has in the past. I have IE 11.0.9600.17278 and update version 11.0.12. I'm stumped so any insight as to a workaround would be great.

### Edit

So now that I've done a little more testing on it, I'm thinking this is a server issue? I created this test file. http://sky-9.com/ie11/ and it works in IE11 all on it's own. I copied those exact files to my live server and tested it there, and it does not work. Leads me to believe there is an issue with Apache 2.2.3 somewhere along the lines? Etags are turned off for EOT files and they are gzip'd... I just tried gziping the file on sky-9 and it still came through just fine.

Also, just to point out that the sky-9.com Apache version is 2.2.15

Comment: can you provide a link to the font files, or better still setup a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: can't do jsfiddle as that would have the CORS problem, thinking of another way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old questions.  But I ran into the issue today so I thought I'd document the solution in case it helps others.

I had a very similar issue where fontello fonts (which load via @font-face) were working great from one server in all browsers including IE 11, but the same exact html/css served up from a different server (in my case Asp.Net Core) worked in all browsers EXCEPT IE. And to be specific the only IE version I care about supporting at this point is IE 11.

I was baffled just like the original poster of this question.  In the end I found the issue which was the cache headers for the one server was configured different than the other server.

The server that was able to get IE 11 to properly render the font-face fonts returned `cache-control:max-age=0` for the font files.  The server that caused the Chinese characters to show up in IE 11 was returning `cache-control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`  To fix the issue I removed the `cache-control` header from responses for font files.  Now the fonts render properly in all browsers including IE 11.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by me by removing of the "Vary" header for the files for IE.

```
<Location ~ \.eot$>
  Header unset Vary
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a website where Apache was giving the `.eot` files a header of `Vary: X-Forwarded-For` and IE11 on Win 8.1 wasn't having it. (Although on Win10 it was happy ‍♂️)